# JSON result returning "None" when sending data to Ubidots from Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python, json, raspberry-pi

I am trying to send data from my soil moisture sensor (which is connected to an ADC which is in turn connected to my Raspberry Pi) to Ubidots.

```
import time
import sys
from time import sleep
import requests
import traceback
import Adafruit_ADS1x15

# Create an ADS1115 ADC (16-bit) instance.
adc = Adafruit_ADS1x15.ADS1115()

GAIN = 1

print('Reading ADS1x15 values, press Ctrl-C to quit...')

while True:
    m = adc.read_adc(0, gain=GAIN)
    payload={'soil humidity':m}
    try:
       r = requests.post('http://things.ubidots.com/api/v1.6/devices/raspberry/?token={A1E-6l4DwwC86SDR6QRTJWXGDwshTGPHFl}', data=payload)
       print('Moisture Level:{0:>6}'.format(m))
       time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
       break
    traceback.print_exc()
```

I am getting the following response:

```
Moisture Level: 26508
None
```

and it keeps on looping on.
Any help how to print a `traceback` for this would also be appreciated.

Link to Ubidots documentation: http://help.ubidots.com/iot-projects-tutorials/diy-raspberry-pi-temperature-system-with-ubidots

Comment: Does this page have any documentation? Is it your personal page?

Comment: use: `print(r.status_code)` --> output: 403

Comment: `r.text` --> `{"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."}`

Comment: @eyllanesc I edited the post with a reference link of Ubidots

Comment: Most likely you need to remove the `{}` from around your token. And for future reference, your token is probably considered like your "password" for the API, so you should probably obscure it in any code you post publicly.

Comment: Use: `import requests

payload={'soil_humidity':100.0}
r = requests.post('http://things.ubidots.com/api/v1.6/devices/raspberry/?token=A1E-6l4DwwC86SDR6QRTJWXGDwshTGPHFl', data=payload)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)`

Comment: Remove the `{}` and the data should be called soil_humidity.

Comment: Getting this on loop: `Moisture Level: 26509
200
{"soil_humidity": [{"status_code": 201}]}
`

Comment: That looks like a success to me.

Comment: Actually got this: `Moisture Level: 26509
200
{"soil_humidity": [{"status_code": 201}]}
Moisture Level: 26506
200
{"soil_humidity": [{"status_code": 201}]}
Moisture Level: 26509
502
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
`

Comment: I edited my codes according to a tutorial(https://ubidots.com/docs/es/devices/raspberrypi.html) from Ubidots and it worked.. Thanks for the comments and help